# Overallocation warning in First Aid in Recovery Mode for mid 2015 Macbook Pro on High Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, disk-utility, high-sierra, apfs

[image] I have a 15” Intel Macbook Pro(mid 2015) on High Sierra.
No operation issues with laptop, but one day I ran First Aid and got the error that a volume in Macintosh HD could not be unmounted so the repair failed.
I ran it again in Recovery Mode and the Macintosh HD was able to be unmounted. As I went down checking the rest, this warning appeared while checking a container: Overallocation Detected on Main Device:(42686064+1) bitmap address (e4ef). See screenshot.
How can I fix this?  Or should I let it go?  I have seen a similar question but not sure if it applies.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why were you running First Aid on a Mac with “no operation issues?”

Comment: I just wanted to check if anything was wrong that was not showing up.  Sort of preventative maintenance.

Comment: Unless you’re experiencing a genuine issue, you shouldn’t be running First Aid

Comment: Then, I assume, there is not a serious problem with my laptop.  Its old.

Comment: No issue at all.

Comment: APFS implementation improves with each OS version. I'd strongly recommend updating to at least Mojave, if you really can't let go of 32-bit apps; otherwise go to Monterey.